# Saving each excel column data to separate textfiles

Tags: excel, file, text, save

Is there a simply way to save excel data populated in N number of columns to N number of respective textfiles?

Say if N=3, then data is saved as columnA.txt, columnB.txt, columnC.txt respective to data in excel columns A, B, and C.

Comment: Why am I getting a minuses in my research efforts? The question is trite but very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the code below. I assumed the number of columns is = 3; you can change it by modifying "For lngColumn = 1 To 3" line. All 3 txt files are being saved to your C: drive (can be also changed in "strFile" line).

```
Sub SaveText()
    Dim lngColumn           As Long
    Dim lngRow              As Long
    Dim strFile             As String

    With Sheet1
        For lngColumn = 1 To 3
            strFile = "F:\Column" & lngColumn & ".txt"
            For lngRow = 1 To .Cells(1, lngColumn).End(xlDown).Row
                Open strFile For Append As #1
                Write #1, .Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Value
                Close #1
            Next lngRow
        Next lngColumn
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope it helps.